# SSL handshake issue on IE 11 with tomcat

Tags: ssl, internet-explorer, tomcat

When I try to access our website through IE11, SSL handshake failed. On IE, following error is displayed.

[SSL Error on IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v768N.png)

I enabled SSL debug logging on tomcat. Result is attached.

[SSL debug log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UifhJ7ptRj17u_1oJEaIuc7xQFYQXzCg)

I also did a packet trace through wireshark. Result is attached.

[Packet Trace](https://drive.google.com/open?id=196mHydaTA0pQKEmWDzzOEyxZlml3Umsh)

Can somebody help me in understanding, why IE sent RST and handshake is unsuccessful?

For convenience, here is the SSL debug log copy.

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
https-jsse-nio2-10443-exec-7, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 175
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1545319557 bytes = { 241, 102, 68, 19, 196, 186, 58, 2, 142, 179, 180, 186, 80, 189, 251, 212, 30, 48, 78, 122, 139, 95, 16, 6, 61, 81, 9, 233 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 29, secp256r1, secp384r1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA256withRSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA512withECDSA
Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:0c:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
Extension extended_master_secret
Unsupported extension type_24, data: 00:10:03:02:01:00
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-3, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
Standard ciphersuite chosen: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
%% Negotiating:  [Session-3, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1545319557 bytes = { 97, 98, 78, 54, 18, 174, 216, 230, 116, 27, 86, 149, 238, 243, 141, 200, 231, 225, 54, 68, 118, 22, 87, 178, 217, 116, 246, 186 }
Session ID:  {92, 28, 181, 133, 160, 19, 139, 114, 99, 216, 10, 155, 173, 137, 237, 25, 140, 59, 153, 195, 245, 204, 179, 49, 89, 205, 42, 221, 126, 28, 147, 57}
Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
Extension extended_master_secret
***
Cipher suite:  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=clockcontroller, OU=WorkForce Software, O=WorkForce Software, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 26867932193095777263289930763858312315175451169911540270469975322434401554593517846489231467419363365037593818036593693556117551448063131659525311661292145333515905286916353710412662237765713687248571705693533912575809165971751779925378770578516513573848298027718280225066822697515300871707147459915587779589377876395738318963921532217111299410821422855058019420912762790697366719695263850247093569765798072591751245131093354944223958262752669165567038947970251243583487419772340666576477861756748688921273067030346748496043574503202045236644578277345107987729325458604284470785207456233675325551660606573693389742779
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Mon Oct 22 08:56:19 EDT 2018,
               To: Thu Oct 19 08:56:19 EDT 2028]
  Issuer: CN=clockcontroller, OU=WorkForce Software, O=WorkForce Software, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    29565e6b]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F4 F5 1B CB 86 A2 7F 5E   25 2C 5D 9D 62 B8 67 45  .......^%,].b.gE
0010: 06 B5 9E 82                                        ....
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 16 F2 4F B7 B3 AC E9 87   27 18 C5 FC 9D 61 FF 58  ..O.....'....a.X
0010: A8 D5 9D D8 BA 9E 5A 1D   E9 96 EC 17 C4 16 09 EB  ......Z.........
0020: 6A F8 5E 3A 62 FC DF 73   13 A6 A7 54 D1 A0 E2 56  j.^:b..s...T...V
0030: 51 C9 7E 55 DA 89 80 1A   30 7E 31 2C 03 C4 90 84  Q..U....0.1,....
0040: 62 B9 AA 6D 0C E0 33 CB   89 59 B3 89 59 48 7F B5  b..m..3..Y..YH..
0050: 55 6B 2F CA 37 E0 96 98   FB 75 73 1C EC 4D A8 3A  Uk/.7....us..M.:
0060: 89 49 C9 EA AC 8A 2F 65   F1 4D 98 74 87 F8 2D 5E  .I..../e.M.t..-^
0070: 89 60 49 17 04 79 F7 EA   D4 B0 C3 FF 0B 6E 98 5C  .`I..y.......n.\
0080: 9D 16 AE 00 09 55 38 DB   78 23 52 68 EC 79 43 16  .....U8.x#Rh.yC.
0090: EF 28 7E 9E 27 7C 31 FD   4F AB 25 A7 13 94 AC 88  .(..'.1.O.%.....
00A0: DE 60 A8 94 15 8D F0 32   AF 7C 3A F8 DA AD 7A EA  .`.....2..:...z.
00B0: FB B4 AF 77 31 8C FC 20   52 CA 36 4A 9F 1A 3E 62  ...w1.. R.6J..>b
00C0: 01 F7 EF 72 FB 06 FC 7F   83 7A 0F FB 71 EA 4C C5  ...r.....z..q.L.
00D0: 0E 14 9D 64 89 7E 85 AE   76 A7 0A 21 4E 3F E5 17  ...d....v..!N?..
00E0: 35 39 DA A8 F5 84 41 C2   38 22 80 73 A0 91 E0 11  59....A.8".s....
00F0: 2D 4F B9 A9 B5 B9 37 7A   25 EE 73 3C 32 23 C6 19  -O....7z%.s<2#..

]
***
*** ECDH ServerKeyExchange
Signature Algorithm SHA256withRSA
Server key: Sun EC public key, 256 bits
  public x coord: 20009119234614195494302209861076680467201992809229109970753322221057487611764
  public y coord: 17012831469688718179923828827485619723638464800697160800297861041710637731326
  parameters: secp256r1 [NIST P-256, X9.62 prime256v1] (1.2.840.10045.3.1.7)
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA224withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=082>
<CN=294>
<CN=1136>
<CN=1363>
<CN=1274>
<CN=1278>
<CN=528>
<CN=107>
<CN=734>
<CN=624>
<CN=104>
<CN=373>
<CN=1407>
<CN=071>
<CN=1000>
<CN=450>
<CN=1330>
<CN=607>
<CN=1353>
<CN=059>
<CN=233>
<CN=151>
<CN=911>
<CN=1272>
<CN=1259>
<CN=815>
<CN=1084>
<CN=1106>
<CN=483>
<CN=575>
<CN=1398>
<CN=357>
<CN=976>
<CN=701>
<CN=605>
<CN=204>
<CN=382>
<CN=455>
<CN=1265>
<CN=914>
<CN=1400>
<CN=363>
<CN=541>
<CN=423>
<CN=391>
<CN=933>
<CN=157>
<CN=197>
<CN=610>
<CN=174>
<CN=1064>
<CN=348>
<CN=1355>
<CN=748>
<CN=955>
<CN=212>
<CN=820>
<CN=105>
<CN=202>
<CN=281>
<CN=823>
<CN=1248>
<CN=685>
<CN=1134>
<CN=220>
<CN=045>
<CN=580>
<CN=1061>
<CN=466>
<CN=987>
<CN=988>
<CN=064>
<CN=1086>
<CN=1364>
<CN=842>
<CN=973>
<CN=460>
<CN=069>
<CN=1307>
<CN=1381>
<CN=291>
<CN=699>
<CN=882>
<CN=1179>
<CN=683>
<CN=499>
<CN=594>
<CN=1045>
<CN=474>
<CN=793>
<CN=871>
<CN=632>
<CN=1216>
<CN=1035>
<CN=870>
<CN=874>
<CN=1463>
<CN=021>
<CN=1180>
<CN=891>
<CN=1011>
<CN=130>
<CN=375>
<CN=315>
<CN=888>
<CN=1004>
<CN=023>
<CN=1176>
<CN=290>
<CN=400>
<CN=969>
<CN=709>
<CN=886>
<CN=1396>
<CN=224>
<CN=1135>
<CN=304>
<CN=1240>
<CN=989>
<CN=358>
<CN=1122>
<CN=1104>
<CN=1389>
<CN=776>
<CN=975>
<CN=1103>
<CN=1303>
<CN=1293>
<CN=1209>
<CN=1166>
<CN=853>
<CN=651>
<CN=781>
<CN=347>
<CN=974>
<CN=694>
<CN=1159>
<CN=049>
<CN=158>
<CN=1297>
<CN=1172>
<CN=526>
<CN=1031>
<CN=1490>
<CN=1024>
<CN=300>
<CN=1076>
<CN=141>
<CN=706>
<CN=381>
<CN=619>
<CN=398>
<CN=1258>
<CN=1139>
<CN=146>
<CN=428>
<CN=703>
<CN=189>
<CN=677>
<CN=166>
<CN=1168>
<CN=1251>
<CN=556>
<CN=1085>
<CN=1001>
<CN=795>
<CN=676>
<CN=999>
<CN=156>
<CN=1074>
<CN=667>
<CN=1038>
<CN=960>
<CN=560>
<CN=501>
<CN=1243>
<CN=1483>
<CN=1420>
<CN=462>
<CN=079>
<CN=1461>
<CN=857>
<CN=851>
<CN=502>
<CN=1414>
<CN=807>
<CN=198>
<CN=1261>
<CN=438>
<CN=472>
<CN=012>
<CN=1187>
<CN=707>
<CN=716>
<CN=238>
<CN=1203>
<CN=554>
<CN=342>
<CN=240>
<CN=1392>
<CN=1315>
<CN=1370>
<CN=520>
<CN=1023>
<CN=881>
<CN=048>
<CN=388>
<CN=210>
<CN=209>
<CN=1090>
<CN=095>
<CN=777>
<CN=1436>
<CN=1108>
<CN=1462>
<CN=409>
<CN=1406>
<CN=979>
<CN=817>
<CN=1354>
<CN=801>
<CN=184>
<CN=540>
<CN=116>
<CN=1464>
<CN=406>
<CN=378>
<CN=691>
<CN=659>
<CN=635>
<CN=1413>
<CN=1302>
<CN=565>
<CN=805>
<CN=121>
<CN=700>
<CN=530>
<CN=1002>
<CN=964>
<CN=385>
<CN=1481>
<CN=616>
<CN=929>
<CN=1142>
<CN=489>
<CN=552>
<CN=956>
<CN=806>
<CN=1422>
<CN=1098>
<CN=328>
<CN=1202>
<CN=1280>
<CN=093>
<CN=578>
<CN=1123>
<CN=753>
<CN=190>
<CN=949>
<CN=1430>
<CN=497>
<CN=1428>
<CN=337>
<CN=1475>
<CN=313>
<CN=1417>
<CN=250>
<CN=159>
<CN=237>
<CN=087>
<CN=215>
<CN=1022>
<CN=915>
<CN=991>
<CN=893>
<CN=840>
<CN=425>
<CN=1079>
<CN=1020>
<CN=128>
<CN=487>
<CN=448>
<CN=1057>
<CN=1041>
<CN=1252>
<CN=216>
<CN=791>
<CN=1286>
<CN=199>
<CN=912>
<CN=1182>
<CN=1115>
<CN=260>
<CN=1394>
<CN=265>
<CN=771>
<CN=814>
<CN=1277>
<CN=479>
<CN=437>
<CN=075>
<CN=1050>
<CN=1371>
<CN=505>
<CN=014>
<CN=887>
<CN=1405>
<CN=231>
<CN=1424>
<CN=177>
<CN=1132>
<CN=033>
<CN=1331>
<CN=203>
<CN=772>
<CN=862>
<CN=416>
<CN=1455>
<CN=1266>
<CN=1010>
<CN=1465>
<CN=549>
<CN=1040>
<CN=1299>
<CN=047>
<CN=491>
<CN=350>
<CN=343>
<CN=006>
<CN=433>
<CN=1184>
<CN=731>
<CN=944>
<CN=1444>
<CN=1095>
<CN=843>
<CN=1291>
<CN=211>
<CN=320>
<CN=982>
<CN=1021>
<CN=135>
<CN=138>
<CN=844>
<CN=797>
<CN=1298>
<CN=031>
<CN=1260>
<CN=1169>
<CN=595>
<CN=747>
<CN=1473>
<CN=072>
<CN=513>
<CN=968>
<CN=846>
<CN=312>
<CN=562>
<CN=938>
<CN=1171>
<CN=1336>
<CN=946>
<CN=867>
<CN=490>
<CN=650>
<CN=1387>
<CN=080>
<CN=162>
<CN=330>
<CN=1015>
<CN=704>
<CN=1219>
<CN=1474>
<CN=755>
<CN=959>
<CN=1088>
<CN=997>
<CN=1003>
<CN=179>
<CN=1033>
<CN=1173>
<CN=621>
<CN=266>
<CN=028>
<CN=894>
<CN=1054>
<CN=427>
<CN=498>
<CN=379>
<CN=305>
<CN=401>
<CN=729>
<CN=1099>
<CN=1344>
<CN=1250>
<CN=219>
<CN=604>
<CN=935>
<CN=317>
<CN=735>
<CN=456>
<CN=1043>
<CN=761>
<CN=311>
<CN=757>
<CN=546>
<CN=684>
<CN=507>
<CN=148>
<CN=061>
<CN=693>
<CN=917>
<CN=1433>
<CN=191>
<CN=1359>
<CN=1263>
<CN=1321>
<CN=108>
<CN=345>
<CN=1144>
<CN=1233>
<CN=074>
<CN=821>
<CN=1411>
<CN=150>
<CN=961>
<CN=037>
<CN=1348>
<CN=1292>
<CN=1440>
<CN=1377>
<CN=279>
<CN=713>
<CN=739>
<CN=647>
<CN=395>
<CN=114>
<CN=407>
<CN=368>
<CN=276>
<CN=262>
<CN=1468>
<CN=1479>
<CN=921>
<CN=322>
<CN=067>
<CN=1231>
<CN=1141>
<CN=147>
<CN=062>
<CN=366>
<CN=1186>
<CN=1154>
<CN=1071>
<CN=570>
<CN=1427>
<CN=393>
<CN=030>
<CN=310>
<CN=452>
<CN=1178>
<CN=1034>
<CN=732>
<CN=636>
<CN=458>
<CN=1016>
<CN=1107>
<CN=1147>
<CN=241>
<CN=896>
<CN=723>
<CN=1454>
<CN=688>
<CN=773>
<CN=1452>
<CN=426>
<CN=1485>
<CN=1198>
<CN=932>
<CN=1236>
<CN=602>
<CN=469>
<CN=985>
<CN=1197>
<CN=206>
<CN=796>
<CN=1489>
<CN=561>
<CN=653>
<CN=759>
<CN=1312>
<CN=1013>
<CN=662>
<CN=032>
<CN=623>
<CN=573>
<CN=115>
<CN=942>
<CN=812>
<CN=1447>
<CN=783>
<CN=1416>
<CN=371>
<CN=1082>
<CN=903>
<CN=780>
<CN=1358>
<CN=1162>
<CN=122>
<CN=022>
<CN=253>
<CN=869>
<CN=800>
<CN=194>
<CN=164>
<CN=365>
<CN=429>
<CN=170>
<CN=506>
<CN=1192>
<CN=1285>
<CN=503>
<CN=1287>
<CN=678>
<CN=1350>
<CN=1237>
<CN=1409>
<CN=178>
<CN=145>
<CN=711>
<CN=858>
<CN=719>
<CN=005>
<CN=1175>
<CN=884>
<CN=1019>
<CN=361>
<CN=947>
<CN=758>
<CN=571>
<CN=1025>
<CN=1322>
<CN=790>
<CN=1294>
<CN=222>
<CN=837>
<CN=389>
<CN=744>
<CN=1130>
<CN=256>
<CN=1431>
<CN=720>
<CN=1459>
<CN=436>
<CN=239>
<CN=113>
<CN=399>
<CN=649>
<CN=163>
<CN=728>
<CN=1174>
<CN=217>
<CN=027>
<CN=100>
<CN=883>
<CN=637>
<CN=1314>
<CN=085>
<CN=1375>
<CN=727>
<CN=945>
<CN=1126>
<CN=970>
<CN=890>
<CN=494>
<CN=779>
<CN=076>
<CN=485>
<CN=1110>
<CN=872>
<CN=998>
<CN=271>
<CN=063>
<CN=1466>
<CN=816>
<CN=1222>
<CN=397>
<CN=447>
<CN=527>
<CN=833>
<CN=825>
<CN=1140>
<CN=1339>
<CN=1068>
<CN=845>
<CN=741>
<CN=1226>
<CN=323>
<CN=864>
<CN=118>
<CN=171>
<CN=1234>
<CN=1380>
<CN=1116>
<CN=1471>
<CN=413>
<CN=1476>
<CN=218>
<CN=432>
<CN=1487>
<CN=1313>
<CN=1451>
<CN=408>
<CN=631>
<CN=041>
<CN=533>
<CN=854>
<CN=588>
<CN=232>
<CN=039>
<CN=1157>
<CN=547>
<CN=213>
<CN=612>
<CN=129>
<CN=629>
<CN=1214>
<CN=254>
<CN=1279>
<CN=994>
<CN=1264>
<CN=470>
<CN=751>
<CN=664>
<CN=332>
<CN=1491>
<CN=967>
<CN=1083>
<CN=1300>
<CN=1146>
<CN=1325>
<CN=1072>
<CN=557>
<CN=172>
<CN=827>
<CN=269>
<CN=1254>
<CN=051>
<CN=740>
<CN=579>
<CN=669>
<CN=550>
<CN=1138>
<CN=834>
<CN=516>
<CN=1097>
<CN=242>
<CN=1111>
<CN=390>
<CN=895>
<CN=514>
<CN=056>
<CN=1362>
<CN=1418>
<CN=316>
<CN=909>
<CN=665>
<CN=1478>
<CN=052>
<CN=1256>
<CN=268>
<CN=272>
<CN=384>
<CN=1027>
<CN=131>
<CN=1442>
<CN=566>
<CN=1094>
<CN=009>
<CN=1402>
<CN=1311>
<CN=1480>
<CN=1469>
<CN=828>
<CN=736>
<CN=134>
<CN=682>
<CN=586>
<CN=1225>
<CN=302>
<CN=717>
<CN=1319>
<CN=778>
<CN=1425>
<CN=951>
<CN=1051>
<CN=270>
<CN=1190>
<CN=077>
<CN=065>
<CN=698>
<CN=860>
<CN=1308>
<CN=1014>
<CN=1161>
<CN=919>
<CN=414>
<CN=569>
<CN=824>
<CN=1205>
<CN=900>
<CN=913>
<CN=1189>
<CN=193>
<CN=1170>
<CN=1112>
<CN=1412>
<CN=482>
<CN=173>
<CN=349>
<CN=937>
<CN=445>
<CN=003>
<CN=642>
<CN=1155>
<CN=461>
<CN=681>
<CN=420>
<CN=1343>
<CN=346>
<CN=1191>
<CN=286>
<CN=690>
<CN=092>
<CN=1360>
<CN=1255>
<CN=904>
<CN=567>
<CN=331>
<CN=591>
<CN=680>
<CN=954>
<CN=808>
<CN=309>
<CN=878>
<CN=633>
<CN=880>
<CN=175>
<CN=421>
<CN=314>
<CN=289>
<CN=1124>
<CN=873>
<CN=1269>
<CN=036>
<CN=1230>
<CN=1153>
<CN=1128>
<CN=1224>
<CN=534>
<CN=730>
<CN=936>
<CN=925>
<CN=1060>
<CN=752>
<CN=186>
<CN=1133>
<CN=525>
<CN=1048>
<CN=1366>
<CN=283>
<CN=972>
<CN=clockcontroller, OU=WorkForce Software, O=WorkForce Software, C=US>
<CN=746>
<CN=1195>
<CN=1437>
<CN=1042>
<CN=524>
<CN=106>
<CN=529>
<CN=1368>
<CN=1316>
<CN=070>
<CN=643>
<CN=750>
<CN=038>
<CN=767>
<CN=435>
<CN=195>
<CN=1143>
<CN=1129>
<CN=251>
<CN=1296>
<CN=089>
<CN=628>
<CN=261>
<CN=227>
<CN=188>
<CN=957>
<CN=248>
<CN=1193>
<CN=892>
<CN=1289>
<CN=1026>
<CN=040>
<CN=922>
<CN=326>
<CN=966>
<CN=1310>
<CN=020>
<CN=356>
<CN=661>
<CN=258>
<CN=411>
<CN=1221>
<CN=1032>
<CN=459>
<CN=725>
<CN=015>
<CN=656>
<CN=096>
<CN=017>
<CN=620>
<CN=587>
<CN=1318>
<CN=582>
<CN=626>
<CN=1125>
<CN=235>
<CN=165>
<CN=334>
<CN=590>
<CN=167>
<CN=154>
<CN=288>
<CN=103>
<CN=756>
<CN=1117>
<CN=905>
<CN=360>
<CN=1337>
<CN=849>
<CN=221>
<CN=931>
<CN=1327>
<CN=386>
<CN=1208>
<CN=1077>
<CN=001>
<CN=818>
<CN=1391>
<CN=153>
<CN=908>
<CN=086>
<CN=417>
<CN=050>
<CN=1206>
<CN=1073>
<CN=668>
<CN=392>
<CN=924>
<CN=1007>
<CN=644>
<CN=1352>
<CN=1301>
<CN=1211>
<CN=1194>
<CN=876>
<CN=1376>
<CN=338>
<CN=263>
<CN=257>
<CN=803>
<CN=1334>
<CN=1069>
<CN=369>
<CN=518>
<CN=127>
<CN=274>
<CN=1446>
<CN=016>
<CN=1284>
<CN=185>
<CN=765>
<CN=083>
<CN=1268>
<CN=1105>
<CN=544>
<CN=101>
<CN=319>
<CN=1120>
<CN=1432>
<CN=509>
<CN=245>
<CN=1435>
<CN=559>
<CN=144>
<CN=362>
<CN=1188>
<CN=712>
<CN=364>
<CN=282>
<CN=1121>
<CN=225>
<CN=663>
<CN=1372>
<CN=543>
<CN=576>
<CN=1056>
<CN=1037>
<CN=517>
<CN=136>
<CN=531>
<CN=424>
<CN=380>
<CN=615>
<CN=285>
<CN=1404>
<CN=126>
<CN=519>
<CN=1046>
<CN=1087>
<CN=1383>
<CN=267>
<CN=838>
<CN=383>
<CN=002>
<CN=1177>
<CN=434>
<CN=648>
<CN=788>
<CN=789>
<CN=899>
<CN=1055>
<CN=354>
<CN=1338>
<CN=1163>
<CN=287>
<CN=1290>
<CN=563>
<CN=1467>
<CN=1439>
<CN=965>
<CN=1183>
<CN=671>
<CN=042>
<CN=865>
<CN=1253>
<CN=584>
<CN=538>
<CN=1093>
<CN=1009>
<CN=830>
<CN=1309>
<CN=1347>
<CN=1472>
<CN=091>
<CN=724>
<CN=259>
<CN=043>
<CN=670>
<CN=596>
<CN=1148>
<CN=1395>
<CN=430>
<CN=264>
<CN=826>
<CN=109>
<CN=140>
<CN=1445>
<CN=1078>
<CN=1257>
<CN=099>
<CN=948>
<CN=1165>
<CN=273>
<CN=993>
<CN=992>
<CN=088>
<CN=234>
<CN=1458>
<CN=1500>
<CN=848>
<CN=1365>
<CN=1220>
<CN=1092>
<CN=1245>
<CN=875>
<CN=813>
<CN=1030>
<CN=094>
<CN=1346>
<CN=589>
<CN=168>
<CN=325>
<CN=901>
<CN=252>
<CN=1429>
<CN=073>
<CN=1218>
<CN=183>
<CN=117>
<CN=1119>
<CN=577>
<CN=1397>
<CN=111>
<CN=536>
<CN=1246>
<CN=1393>
<CN=769>
<CN=831>
<CN=971>
<CN=1332>
<CN=614>
<CN=053>
<CN=415>
<CN=418>
<CN=708>
<CN=058>
<CN=029>
<CN=412>
<CN=782>
<CN=512>
<CN=1357>
<CN=229>
<CN=1448>
<CN=1497>
<CN=775>
<CN=1379>
<CN=714>
<CN=835>
<CN=1062>
<CN=372>
<CN=500>
<CN=859>
<CN=453>
<CN=1239>
<CN=963>
<CN=1374>
<CN=1270>
<CN=1044>
<CN=084>
<CN=055>
<CN=1275>
<CN=810>
<CN=298>
<CN=1181>
<CN=564>
<CN=007>
<CN=522>
<CN=877>
<CN=745>
<CN=766>
<CN=1388>
<CN=1100>
<CN=1382>
<CN=277>
<CN=1006>
<CN=1212>
<CN=476>
<CN=1039>
<CN=996>
<CN=1109>
<CN=1460>
<CN=161>
<CN=119>
<CN=1118>
<CN=187>
<CN=980>
<CN=511>
<CN=123>
<CN=1434>
<CN=743>
<CN=1151>
<CN=297>
<CN=1410>
<CN=1207>
<CN=655>
<CN=718>
<CN=336>
<CN=454>
<CN=327>
<CN=930>
<CN=822>
<CN=953>
<CN=292>
<CN=1323>
<CN=024>
<CN=1317>
<CN=733>
<CN=396>
<CN=1213>
<CN=1199>
<CN=1283>
<CN=284>
<CN=444>
<CN=923>
<CN=214>
<CN=601>
<CN=645>
<CN=726>
<CN=201>
<CN=1361>
<CN=1242>
<CN=640>
<CN=861>
<CN=1340>
<CN=1326>
<CN=493>
<CN=1295>
<CN=180>
<CN=120>
<CN=608>
<CN=572>
<CN=1276>
<CN=1066>
<CN=1127>
<CN=344>
<CN=149>
<CN=1018>
<CN=568>
<CN=852>
<CN=1244>
<CN=798>
<CN=868>
<CN=060>
<CN=542>
<CN=523>
<CN=367>
<CN=1167>
<CN=1498>
<CN=532>
<CN=1356>
<CN=410>
<CN=255>
<CN=599>
<CN=1477>
<CN=1200>
<CN=786>
<CN=341>
<CN=247>
<CN=1499>
<CN=1450>
<CN=335>
<CN=403>
<CN=078>
<CN=1160>
<CN=200>
<CN=098>
<CN=666>
<CN=419>
<CN=539>
<CN=829>
<CN=301>
<CN=026>
<CN=646>
<CN=768>
<CN=990>
<CN=1036>
<CN=008>
<CN=794>
<CN=1482>
<CN=299>
<CN=1053>
<CN=638>
<CN=359>
<CN=1441>
<CN=125>
<CN=081>
<CN=464>
<CN=995>
<CN=137>
<CN=1215>
<CN=928>
<CN=1081>
<CN=958>
<CN=333>
<CN=1385>
<CN=449>
<CN=613>
<CN=1494>
<CN=181>
<CN=836>
<CN=600>
<CN=1328>
<CN=443>
<CN=370>
<CN=1349>
<CN=340>
<CN=687>
<CN=611>
<CN=496>
<CN=1384>
<CN=1271>
<CN=1185>
<CN=885>
<CN=819>
<CN=1065>
<CN=1210>
<CN=353>
<CN=1453>
<CN=1049>
<CN=439>
<CN=658>
<CN=934>
<CN=1341>
<CN=249>
<CN=521>
<CN=013>
<CN=351>
<CN=169>
<CN=792>
<CN=774>
<CN=537>
<CN=606>
<CN=1114>
<CN=548>
<CN=035>
<CN=784>
<CN=1008>
<CN=422>
<CN=394>
<CN=804>
<CN=907>
<CN=1158>
<CN=721>
<CN=1249>
<CN=770>
<CN=710>
<CN=275>
<CN=545>
<CN=749>
<CN=902>
<CN=555>
<CN=764>
<CN=1267>
<CN=939>
<CN=627>
<CN=374>
<CN=155>
<CN=705>
<CN=981>
<CN=715>
<CN=1149>
<CN=742>
<CN=307>
<CN=1320>
<CN=352>
<CN=1449>
<CN=208>
<CN=1378>
<CN=1367>
<CN=802>
<CN=639>
<CN=879>
<CN=057>
<CN=760>
<CN=1204>
<CN=597>
<CN=689>
<CN=477>
<CN=672>
<CN=738>
<CN=473>
<CN=019>
<CN=243>
<CN=465>
<CN=207>
<CN=1421>
<CN=133>
<CN=467>
<CN=1232>
<CN=244>
<CN=978>
<CN=1047>
<CN=697>
<CN=068>
<CN=660>
<CN=025>
<CN=641>
<CN=1150>
<CN=617>
<CN=855>
<CN=1102>
<CN=481>
<CN=1101>
<CN=468>
<CN=799>
<CN=763>
<CN=112>
<CN=182>
<CN=223>
<CN=1386>
<CN=1113>
<CN=1288>
<CN=920>
<CN=143>
<CN=1005>
<CN=1403>
<CN=1345>
<CN=230>
<CN=1401>
<CN=609>
<CN=280>
<CN=598>
<CN=1304>
<CN=488>
<CN=1470>
<CN=1273>
<CN=926>
<CN=811>
<CN=484>
<CN=510>
<CN=673>
<CN=1486>
<CN=1017>
<CN=832>
<CN=654>
<CN=1415>
<CN=515>
<CN=1012>
<CN=1329>
<CN=1063>
<CN=1052>
<CN=1137>
<CN=387>
<CN=592>
<CN=977>
<CN=558>
<CN=306>
<CN=762>
<CN=1495>
<CN=1228>
<CN=1080>
<CN=321>
<CN=226>
<CN=492>
<CN=847>
<CN=246>
<CN=278>
<CN=471>
<CN=630>
<CN=551>
<CN=451>
<CN=695>
<CN=625>
<CN=889>
<CN=1029>
<CN=622>
<CN=906>
<CN=696>
<CN=440>
<CN=1484>
<CN=1145>
<CN=535>
<CN=856>
<CN=1164>
<CN=754>
<CN=634>
<CN=1028>
<CN=1456>
<CN=1496>
<CN=574>
<CN=124>
<CN=950>
<CN=1373>
<CN=1390>
<CN=097>
<CN=984>
<CN=495>
<CN=446>
<CN=983>
<CN=110>
<CN=839>
<CN=010>
<CN=986>
<CN=910>
<CN=1457>
<CN=1217>
<CN=898>
<CN=034>
<CN=1335>
<CN=1058>
<CN=1229>
<CN=329>
<CN=431>
<CN=1342>
<CN=1333>
<CN=785>
<CN=692>
<CN=722>
<CN=192>
<CN=1369>
<CN=1282>
<CN=1152>
<CN=943>
<CN=553>
<CN=1247>
<CN=011>
<CN=674>
<CN=809>
<CN=318>
<CN=1426>
<CN=478>
<CN=1488>
<CN=863>
<CN=1059>
<CN=402>
<CN=1075>
<CN=004>
<CN=504>
<CN=1281>
<CN=508>
<CN=160>
<CN=1305>
<CN=377>
<CN=581>
<CN=652>
<CN=102>
<CN=657>
<CN=1223>
<CN=296>
<CN=303>
<CN=1438>
<CN=018>
<CN=1492>
<CN=441>
<CN=1235>
<CN=1241>
<CN=293>
<CN=1306>
<CN=152>
<CN=1408>
<CN=1262>
<CN=916>
<CN=139>
<CN=927>
<CN=1238>
<CN=176>
<CN=376>
<CN=593>
<CN=585>
<CN=405>
<CN=486>
<CN=404>
<CN=1399>
<CN=046>
<CN=940>
<CN=1196>
<CN=1227>
<CN=132>
<CN=457>
<CN=142>
<CN=737>
<CN=1493>
<CN=463>
<CN=675>
<CN=897>
<CN=1351>
<CN=841>
<CN=066>
<CN=1443>
<CN=205>
https-jsse-nio2-10443-exec-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 16383
*** ServerHelloDone
https-jsse-nio2-10443-exec-7, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 12558
https-jsse-nio2-10443-exec-9, called closeOutbound()
https-jsse-nio2-10443-exec-9, closeOutboundInternal()
https-jsse-nio2-10443-exec-9, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
https-jsse-nio2-10443-exec-9, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
```

Tomcat connector configuration is,

```
<Connector port="10443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol" maxHttpHeaderSize="4096"
           maxThreads="1050" minSpareThreads="25"
           maxKeepAliveRequests="-1" keepAliveTimeout="180000"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="10" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
           connectionTimeout="180000"
           keystoreFile="file.keystore"
           keystorePass="file.pass" algorithm="SunX509"
           truststoreFile="file.keystore"
           truststorePass="file.pass"
           truststoreType="JKS"
           keyAlias="tomcat"
           compression="on"
           compressionMinSize="2048"
           trustManagerClassName="com.tomcatssl.CustomTrustManager"
           useServerCipherSuitesOrder="true"
           ciphers="TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV"
           server="Clock Web Server"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/js,text/css"/>
```

Thank You

Comment: How much can you post into SO? I (and others) probably don't want to download files just to read your question. You should post your Tomcat `<Connector>` configuration.

Comment: I tried to provide as much information as possible in question now. Thank You

Comment: Try running [Qualys's ssltest](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) against your site. It will tell you if your TLS stack is configured appropriately.

Comment: What happens if you remove the explicit `ciphers` configuration, restart Tomcat, and try MSIE11 again? If you are able to handshake, what cipher suite is chosen?

Comment: Removing explicit ciphers configuration had no impact and error was same. The cipher chosen was TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 which is the same when I provided explicit configuration.

Comment: This error is reproducible only when I am using same file for both keystore and truststore and my truststore has large number of entries. I have to use a truststore due to nature of my application and probably unlike good practice I have been using same file for both keystore and truststore. If I just temporarily point keystore to another file than the original file also containing truststore entries, SSL handshake succeeds. Also if I don't have large number of entries in truststore and I am using same file for both keystore and truststore, SSL handshake got succeeded.

Comment: Sounds like the easiest thing to do is to use separate keystore and truststore files. It's very easy to do, so just do it.

Comment: Definitely yes. I was curious though on understanding things that is happening behind the scene. Also curious to know why was this not working on one browser only while working on all other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what would cause some browsers to work differently than others *for sure*, but I do have a guess.

When a server has a trust store configured (for a `<Connector>/<SSLHostConfig>`), it will advertise the list of trusted certificates *to the client* during the initial TLS handshake. If you have a huge number of certificates in your trust store, the server will (of course) send them all. If the client isn't expecting to receive a large number of certificates, it *may* fail when it runs out of space in e.g. a buffer to hold such things. My guess is that MSIE chokes on the long list of acceptable client certificates.

It's unusual for a server to use a `<Connector>/<SSLHostConfig>` with a large number of certificates in its trust store. Typically, if you need to trust certificates *en masse*, you generate a CA certificate and use it to sign the individual client certificates, keeping *only* that CA certificate in your trust store.

If you have a JVM-wide trust store being used for *outgoing* connections, then you might have a lot of certificates in there. You definitely don't want to use that one for the `<Connector>/<SSLHostConfig>` on your server. You should use a separate trust-store that contains only the certificates you expect to trust as *client TLS certificates*. Any other configuration is not secure.

For example, let's say you have VeriSign's root certificate in your trust store. That means anyone who has a client certificate signed by VeriSign can establish a connection with your server. That includes clients *outside* your organization or circle of trust. You should only include certificates in your trust store that you 100% trust every certificate they could ever have signed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your root certificate is trusted by the browser. For your case, the root is "Cisco Umbrella Root CA", which is not trusted. Follow these steps to import the certificate in browser : https://freesslcert.org/trust-freesslcert-in-browser

Comment: Please include the relevant steps from the link in case the link goes down.

Comment: HI Yaron, the link is up. Please check now.

Comment: Hey, I see it's back up but SO doesn't rely on links as permanent information source, links should be used to prove that you're right but the proposed solution should appear here in case the data in the link will be changed or removed once again.